# Android is it possible compile more that one cmake project with externalNativeBuild?

Tags: android, build, cmake, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

So we have an native cmake project that we would like to compile with android studio/gradle by utilizing the externalNativeBuild. The cmake of the project uses **find_package** to "find" other cmake packages that are then included to the target. These are packages that I need to compile (for android) and install or course. I would like to do that in gradle just like with the main project but it seems that one cannot define more that one cmake project to be build in gradle.
Am I correct here? How can we achieve such a build?